# Why does Google Chrome automatically add www. prefix for some websites but it does not add it for others?

Tags: subdomain, google-chrome

It adds it to my website but it does not add it to google.org for example. My website DNS records looks like the following:

```
Host Name | IP Address/Url | Record Type   | TTL
@         | <server ip>    | A (Address)   | 1800
www       | @              | CNAME (Alias) | 1800
```

I may decide to point the www sub-domain to another server (even if it is not recommended), why does chrome consider it is alright to automatically add the www sub-domain? Does it analyze at the DNS records before deciding to add the prefix?

**Edit**: Interesting how if I navigate to www.google.org, then the next time I try to get to google.org, chrome automatically adds the prefix even if it didn't do that before. Strange and nondeterministic behavior in my opinion.

**Edit2**: As another user pointed out, it may be an issue caused by **Settings -> Show advanced settings -> uncheck Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar or the app launcher search box** setting.

**How to reproduce** (using my faculty's website):

1. Type `ace.tuiasi.ro` in the Google Chrome. It should navigate to `www.ace.tuiasi.ro` and it works
2. Now type `ace.tuiasi.ro` in the Mozilla Firefox. It navigates to `ace.tuiasi.ro` and it does not work (because they have a bad DNS configuration and only the www. sub-domain points to the actual server ip).

**Notice**: Because it may be related to their suggestion engine, it may not reproduce in your case.

**Edit3**: Ok, so I noticed that I have to type the `http://` prefix so that I can bypass Chrome's suggestion engine in comparison with Firefox, where I can type it without the prefix. I think this tricked me into thinking it does this every time, when it doesn't. I will close the question as solved.

Comment: Please add several examples so the issue could be reproduced

Comment: Based on the given example it looks like that the issue is strongly related to the cache

Comment: The issue does not seem to be restricted to Chrome. If one navigates to `msn.com` in firefox it navigates to `www.msn.com` as well.

Comment: It may not be the best example. On my website, Firefox does not add the www prefix. But a better example is my faculty website, which only works with the www prefix. Type `ace.tuiasi.ro` in chrome and it goes to `www.ace.tuiasi.ro` and it works, now type `ace.tuiasi.ro` in firefox, and it goes to `ace.tuiasi.ro` and it does not work (because they didn't configured their DNS correctly). Hope this is a better example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so I noticed that I have to type the `http://` prefix so that I can bypass Chrome’s suggestion engine in comparison with Firefox, where I can type it without the prefix. I think this tricked me into thinking it does this every time, when in fact it doesn’t, it was only my history that appeared as suggestion, and I used the `www`. variant in the past.

I will close the question as solved.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue trying to browse to an internal webpage that's not available to the public internet. 
Disabling the prediction service didn't cause the "www" to stop being prepended to the domain string.  Typing http://... and https//... also didn't help.

In my case it was working fine in incognito mode.

It was only after I cleared my cookie data that it started working again.

- Settings > Advanced > Privacy > "Clear browsing data..."
- Check "Cookies and other site and plugin data" (other checkboxes shouldn't be necessary)
- Click "Clear browsing data"

I'd guess if you have a browser plugin that lets you edit cookies, you could just delete cookies for that site before you try the above if you'd prefer not to wipe ALL of your browser cookie data and log yourself out of everything.  In my case it was a relatively new browser install so I didn't mind YOLO-ing it.

To clarify how this answers the OP's question, it's possible for cookie/site data to interfere with the way your URLs are resolved, so if the accepted answer doesn't explain it, this might.

Comment: NB: For me, Chrome wouldn't stop adding `www.` subdomain even after I searched and deleted all relevant history, cookies, and local storage. It only resolved when I cleared all browsing data except cookies and passwords.

Comment: You can also do this in Firefox non-destructively by opening the dev tools, going to settings and selecting "Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)" then refreshing the page.